# Ifelse with time range

Tags: r

Currently, I use the Sys.Date() for the filename on a daily basis.

```
timestamp <- Sys.Date()
```

Since I'm increasing the outputs per Day to 3 I would like to adjust the filename based on a specific time range.

If the system time is between

- 22:00 - 05:59 = 3
- 06:00 - 13:59 = 1
- 14:00 - 21:59 = 2

How can I get the Sys.Date() + this 1,2 or 3 as a filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Sys.time()` to get timestamp, extract hour from it and return a number based on hour of the day.

```
timestamp <- Sys.time()  
hour <- as.integer(format(timestamp, '%H'))
names <- if(hour >= 20 || hour <= 5) '3' else if(hour >= 6 && hour <= 13) '1' else '2'
paste(as.Date(timestamp), names, sep = "_")
```

Comment: Do you know how to add this into my current approach?
timestamp <- Sys.Date()  
filename <- paste0("C:/Users/XXX/XXX",timestamp,".csv")  
output <- as.data.frame(dataset)
write.csv(output, file = filename)